# Identify the text pattern on image and get the string values to a text file

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, tesseract, emgucv

I am working on an image which has the text on it. 
Text example: X4 200 , X3 400, X8 2o and the same type of text present on image.
I need to read the X4 and corresponding value from C#,and then i need to save those values in a text file.
Please let me know how can i start with it.
I am trying with this code on button click event.

```
'   OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if(ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image =(Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
        }
        using (var tEngine = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube)) 
            {
                using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(ofd.FileName))
                {                        
                    using (var page = tEngine.Process(img)) 
                    {
                        var text = page.GetText(); 
                        textBox1.Text = text;
                    }
                }
```

'

image is here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgcpZ.png

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi , i have updated the question.please let me know your views

Comment: @CharanS Can you share the image as well? You might need to do quite some preprocessing first.

Comment: @JeruLuke , kindly check the attached Image .